# Possible to apply CSS to a table heading depending on the name/label within the heading?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have roughly 200 tables on my site. All of them are set up the same way, so making a change on one of them, changes all of them.

It would be extremely time consuming to go through each table and give it a class name.

Is it possible to apply css, depending on the text within the table?

For example, my table would look like this:

```
<tr>
<th colspan="2">Table 1</th>
</tr>
```

Then what I want is:
If th has text "Table 1" then apply this css:

```
th {
 background-color: #b2591a;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that you can do it using CSS, but you can using javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text

Comment: Yep javascript is your friend here. Remember it will break if someone has js turned off in their browser. I would suggest if it's only one table to add a class to that table then you can use css.

Comment: you can do it with also jquery: $('td:contains("Table 1")')